# Full background image initially fixed, then scrolls when DIV content ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to figure out how to have a full background image (background-size: cover) be fixed initially (the text over the image scrolls while the image stays put), but, at the moment when the user scrolls down to the end of the content (like a tall block of text), the background then scrolls up revealing a new section/div below.

For example:

```
<section id="top-section-with-fixed-bg">
   <div class="tall-content-1500px">
      <p>Text that's really tall</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section id="next-section">
   ...
</section>
```

But, again, the background image is fixed until the user has scrolled down 1500px and the content for that section/div is done. At that point, the user continues to scroll and the background image scrolls up.

Not, as with parallax solutions, with the background image being covered by the next section. But the background image going up with the scroll.

I'm thinking this takes some javascript, jQuery fixing, but I'm still a bit novice with it. I'm a designer just wanting a site to look and act this certain way. I'm guessing I have to recognize the height of the content, where that ends, and then either tell the CSS to switch from fixed to scroll (without effecting the position of the image), or having the js move the image up with the scroll action.

Update: Here's a quickly tossed together [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1a9mykL/embedded/result/)

UPDATED UPDATE:
I think I've found the solution!

With the pointers provided in responses here, then some digging around, I have it kind of working.

I started with trying to figure out how to detect the window height. I plug that into the text/content DIV, using that value for the DIVs height. This is important, to set the container for the text to the height of the user's window, not to a specific height. Then, I set that DIV to overflow: auto (and hide the scrollbar, for aesthetics). That allowed me to set a trigger so when the end of the content in that DIV is reached, the background-attachment is changed from fixed to scroll.

And, voila! It's not perfect, and I'm sure some real javascript/jQuery experts will right my wrongs on it, but I like how far I've gotten with this so far.

I realize that the swtich from fixed to scroll is probably unnecessary. At the moment, when the switch happens, the image jumps a little to adjust to the window size and its own position, now being set to scroll. If I set the CSS originally to fixed, and make sure the content of the DIV (using padding wisely) to cover the window, as the user scrolls with the mouse the correct action will occur: text scrolls until there is no more text, then the image scrolls up.

Check it out and look forward to help and comments.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1a9mykL/5/embedded/result/)

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: Here are some ideas on different ways to accomplish this https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: The OP is looking for the way to scroll the background image after a certain height, not how to make a background image.

Comment: Yeah; the second section in that fiddle I tossed together would be where once the user reaches the end of the content vertically, that background image now starts to scroll up as well.

Comment: Why are you using JS to set the height to the height of the window in pixels instead of setting the height to 100% in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

have you set `background-attachment:fixed;`? This makes background images 'move' with the browser scroll. Be careful when it comes to devices though as this method can cause 'laggy looking sites' because there's too much render for the device (depending on image).

I personally target 'large' and 'modern' browsers with this:

```
@media query and (max-width:600px){
    .top-section-with-fixed-bg{background-attachment:fixed;}
}
```

EDIT:

sorry I didn't fully understand the question. Here's some CSS to get you going

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
    //document.body.scrollTop would be the windows scroll position.
    if(document.body.scrollTop==1500px)
            document.getElementById('top-section-with-fixed-bg').style.backgroundAttachment='static';
    }else document.getElementById('top-section-with-fixed-bg').style.backgroundAttachment='fixed';
});
```

I'm very sorry but this is very basic. I'm about to finish work. The function could use a bit of sprucing up a bit like making it dynamic. This is also only native JS. So it's not all that fancy but you get the idea. When the document.body.scrollTop is at the bottom of your element. Which I'm guessing is 1500px tall? IF not use offsetHeight(). That'll give you the complete height of the element including padding and margins and I think borders as well?

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He wants the background image to be fixed at first, and become unfixed and scroll to reveal a new background image when a certain height is reached.

Comment: @tomysshadow ahh ok, couldn't really tell haha, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Yes, SourRaspberri. It's set to fixed. But I would like it, essentially, to switch to 'scroll' once the user has scrolled to the end of that particular content, and the next section starts below it. Like tomysshadow was saying.

Either I'm missing something that can be done with just CSS, or there's some js that's alluding me or, more likely, beyond me.

Also, I'm not concerned at this point with going down to mobile sizes. I'm planning on changing things around for mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I figured out a solution and your response gave me some good direction. Check out the update to the original post and would love your thoughts.

Comment: It's not a bad method, although you do not put the method back to the original settings. I still don't see why though to be honest lol sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'd set your background images to background-position: fixed; then put the next background image at the bottom of the text so it overlays on top of the first div. Problem is you can't have the nice `<section>` structure you had going before.

```
<style type="text/css">
.section-with-fixed-bg {
   min-height: 100%;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}

#bg-1 {
   background-image: url("./background-1.jpg");
}

#bg-2 {
   background-image: url("./background-2.jpg");
}

#bg-2 {
   background-image: url("./background-3.jpg");
}
</style>
...
<body>
<div id="bg-1" class="section-with-fixed-bg">
   <p>Text that's really tall</p>
   <div id="bg-2" class="section-with-fixed-bg">
      <p>Next section of text that's really tall.</p>
      <div id="bg-3" class="section-with-fixed-bg">
         <p>Next section of text that's really tall.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I haven't tested this but it should cause the new image to overlap the old one, at least in theory.

Comment: While it overlaps, the background image itself doesn't scroll up once the end of the content is reached.

Comment: Check out my update above with a possible solution. Would love your thoughts.